# Multicast packet not reaching phone from ethernet

Tags: android, networking, multicast, lan, jmdns

I am unable to send a udp multicast/broadcast packet, from a laptop 'wired' to a wifi router, to an android phone connected to the same router wirelessly. It works the other way round(phone to laptop). Also, the phone can receive a packet if I explicitly specify the phone ip address in my code. 
Secondly, there is no issue if both devices are connected via wifi.
I have even tried jmdns but the same problem occurs. 
What could possibly be the issue? Any router misconfiguration? Plz help.

Comment: This is probably caused by the router not forwarding broadcast UDP; the best way to check this is to connect the laptop wirelessly, and re-run the phone-to-laptop broadcast. What is the router make/model?

Comment: Everything works perfectly when I connect the laptop wirelessly. The  issue occurs specifically when I connect the laptop using an ethernet cable. It's weird because they are on the same subnet and both receive internal ip addresses from the router. And I don't think it's a specific router issue as the same problem occurred on my friend's dlink router as well.

Comment: If it works as expected when you've got the laptop and phone connected wirelessly to the same AP, then this must be a problem with the router not forwarding ethernet broadcast packets to wifi; without details on the router, I don't think anyone can help you.

Comment: It's a router provided by my dsl service provider. The Model is Beetel 450TC1 ADSL2+.

Comment: Is your machine able to receive multicast traffic... You can check in wireshark... at port 5353...

Answer (score 0):

You should acquire a [MulticastLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.MulticastLock.html) before attempting to receive any multicast data. On some HTC devices, this also applies to receiving broadcast traffic. You can acquire a multicast lock using the [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html).

Comment: I've done that and there's no problem in the code. As I mentioned before, multicast packets are received by my phone when I connect my laptop wirelessly. The issue occurs when I connect my laptop using an ethernet cable.

Comment: Do you have another computer to see if the problem is localized to your laptop? Do you have another PC hooked up to the router to see if when you use ethernet, the multicast packet is actually making it to that PC as well? Have you used wireshark on the laptop to see if the multicast packet is going out the way you expect it to on the laptop itself?

Comment: I tried using another laptop and it worked temporarily and then stopped. Really weird. So I assume it's not a router issue. I noticed problems occur when I switch back and forth from wireless to ethernet. eg: if wireless works properly and i switch to ethernet, sending might not work but when i switch back to wireless, everything starts working again. very strange.

Comment: I see. The best way to debug these kinds of things is with Wireshark. You can see what packets are being sent and if you are receiving them. Running it on both laptops should give you an idea where the problem lies. How do you know your phone isn't receiving the traffic anymore? Have you used a WifiLock and a WakeLock to make sure your wi-fi & CPU are not turning off.

Comment: I found a workaround. I've to restart my laptop everytime I want to switch from wireless to ethernet. (Ethernet to wireless transition is smooth) Otherwise, I assume the laptop does not multicast the packet. And therefore, the phone does not receive it. Although I'll have to confirm this using wireshark. Need to learn how to use it. Upon restart, packets are multicasted properly and the phone receives it. All this while, the app on the phone remains untouched. So it's most probably a laptop issue (specifically, lan card). At the most, a router issue, but highly unlikely.

Comment: It would seem that way yea. Are you sure its not the test application you are using? I would imagine you have brought that down and up after switching interfaces?

Comment: No, the app on the phone remains active. It just receives udp multicast packets and displays a chat message like a messenger.

Comment: Sorry I meant the app on your laptop. Do you bring that down and up when you switch from WiFi to Ethernet?

Comment: Yes, I tried rerunning the code upon switching but to no avail. I have to reboot everytime I need to use multicasting on ethernet. And the weird part is that this problem is restricted to multicast/broadcast packets. If I explicitly specify my phone ip address, it works fine anyways! Perhaps, an issue with the NIC driver...

Comment: while developing FrostWire for android we ended up relying on both multicast and broadcast to have phones finding each other (and laptops) on the same network (ethernet + wifi).

Even if your code looks perfect it seems to be a matter of how multicast has been implemented in the different routers/switches. And we've learned that most WiFi routers out there really suck, not only when it comes to multicast, but specially when it comes to UPnP and port forwarding.

Comment: Just for the record, problems occurred due to my wireless router having an issue. It sometimes forwards multicast packets when I perform a 'sysrestart'. Most of the times it doesn't. Has to be a firmware issue.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, but fixed, is a router config issue.

In my case, had to activate "IGMP snooping" on my router config menu (advanced->LAN) AND the "standard mode" instead of blocking mode.

This made my router to transmit all multicast packets from ethernet over wifi.

Anyway, you might not have exactly the same router as me, just try to find similar features in your own model.